# SSH dynamic forwarding proxy - "No data received" in chrome

Tags: ssh, proxy

My debug log:

```
ssh -D 5000 root@103.117.102.43 -vvv
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/config line 12: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/tmp/master-root@103.117.102.43:22" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 103.117.102.43 [103.117.102.43] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "103.117.102.43" from file "/Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 126/256
debug2: bits set: 511/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 4a:d7:4c:0b:0c:1e:2f:78:f9:dc:ef:e5:29:c7:3f:18
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "103.117.102.43" from file "/Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '103.117.102.43' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug2: bits set: 478/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa.cn6 (0x7fe09340b5c0),
debug2: key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fe093500290),
debug2: key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa.cn6
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/zhenweiliu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@103.117.102.43's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 60 padlen 4 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 103.117.102.43 ([103.117.102.43]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5000 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 5 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5000.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5000.
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /tmp/master-root@103.117.102.43:22.03MBQJpncB2ft4eB
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [/tmp/master-root@103.117.102.43:22]
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 2 fd 7
debug1: channel 3: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 3
debug2: channel 3: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 3
debug2: channel 3: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env CLICOLOR
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env __CHECKFIX1436934
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 3: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 3: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 3
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 3
debug2: channel 3: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 3
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 3
Linux (none) 3.12.9-x86_64-linode37 #1 SMP Mon Feb 3 10:01:02 EST 2014 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

My SwitchySharp config in Chrome
127.0.0.1 5000

Then I visit google and it shows:
No data received

Debug log

```
debug1: Connection to port 5000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 11 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug1: Connection to port 5000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 12 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 12 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 12 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug1: Connection to port 5000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 13 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 13 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 13 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 6: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 2155
debug2: channel 4: zombie
debug2: channel 4: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 4: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 7
debug3: channel 4: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)
  #5 dynamic-tcpip (t13 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 12/12 cc -1)
  #6 dynamic-tcpip (t13 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 13/13 cc -1)

debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug1: Connection to port 5000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 11 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 2155
debug2: channel 4: zombie
debug2: channel 4: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 4: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 7
debug3: channel 4: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)
  #5 dynamic-tcpip (t13 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 12/12 cc -1)
  #6 dynamic-tcpip (t13 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 13/13 cc -1)

debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: read<=0 rfd 12 len 0
debug2: channel 5: not open
debug2: channel 5: zombie
debug2: channel 5: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 5: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 6
debug3: channel 5: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)
  #6 dynamic-tcpip (t13 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 13/13 cc -1)

debug2: channel 6: read<=0 rfd 13 len 0
debug2: channel 6: not open
debug2: channel 6: zombie
debug2: channel 6: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 6: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 5
debug3: channel 6: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)

debug1: Connection to port 5000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 11 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 11 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 4: pre_dynamic: have 1064
debug2: channel 4: zombie
debug2: channel 4: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 4: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 5
debug3: channel 4: status: The following connections are open:
  #3 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 8/9 cc -1)
```

How can I fix this ? thx :D

Comment: How did you set up the proxy in chrome? Did you specifically set chrome to use a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: Hi @Kenster. Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved this problem
The problem is I set the Chrome proxy setting wrong.
I write the proxy host and port in the "HTTP proxy" line. This is wrong.
I should write them just in the "SOCKS proxy" line and left the other blank